# Getting second-degree polynomial for the curve fitting by changing slightly the code I write for linear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
sales=np.array([72,180,279,378,495,585,693,792,855,873,801,648,612,477,396])
indexes=np.arange(1,16)

plt.plot(indexes,sales,'ro',label='Projected Sales')

m,b=np.polyfit(indexes,sales,1)
plt.plot(indexes,m*indexes+b,color='blue',label='Best Fit - Projected Sales')

plt.legend()
```

Hello, the code I write works to draw the linear regression, but I need second-degree polynomial for the curve fitting. There is so many different solutions for it, but I'd like to have a code for second-degree plynomial, which is not so different the code I write for linear regression. I mean, I want to change my code for linear regression slightly and get the polynomial curve, I don't need a completely new code, please pay attention to that, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy provides with [`polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) the corresponding evaluation function for `polyfit`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
sales=np.array([72,180,279,378,495,585,693,792,855,873,801,648,612,477,396])
indexes=np.arange(1,16)

plt.plot(indexes,sales,'ro',label='Projected Sales')

p = np.polyfit(indexes,sales,2)
plt.plot(indexes,np.polyval(p, indexes),color='blue',label='Best Fit - Projected Sales')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Obviously, the graphic representation is lacking finesse because you only evaluate your curve on your data points. A better approach would be:

```
....
p = np.polyfit(indexes,sales,2)

xfit=np.linspace(min(indexes),max(indexes), 1000)
yfit=np.polyval(p, xfit)
plt.plot(xfit,yfit,color='blue',label='Best Fit - Projected Sales')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Do we need 1000 here? 'xfit=np.linspace(min(indexes),max(indexes), 1000)' because it works without it, thanks by the way.

Comment: Your image, your rules. If you just want to see the fitted curve, no need to have a smooth curve. If you want to send this to a client, you may want to make it look better. Sorry, btw, that business is going downhill.